# LC-3 .BLKW How it works

Tags: assembly, lc3

Solved!

I am writing a program in assembly for LC-3 that is supposed to wait for the user to type all the characters he wants, then print them on the monitor only after he hits enter.

I got so far to solve the issue if the user only hits the enter button.
Examples:

I press enter  ---> program behaves as it should. (goes to new line and halts)

I press "ABCDEF"   ---> program displays "F" instead of going to new line and displaying ABCDEF.  Solved

.BLKW is supposed to save a block of memory. SO to solve this issue I was supposed to load a .blkw to a register, then store the new letter value into that register and each time update the storage location to move to the next location.

```
            LEA    R2 INPUT
    onemoretime    GETC

        ADD    R3 R1 R0
        BRz    DONE
        STR    R0 R2 0
        ADD    R2 R2 1
        BR     onemoretime        

INPUT      .BLKW 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just adding the ascii values of the input into ONE location, *INPUT*. If you hope to recover the input characters, you need to store them to DIFFERENT locations.

Comment: Yes, but the input is supposed to save each input in a new memory location. (By using .BLKW)

Comment: You have declared an array of 999 words, but you only use the first element of it.